# Storage duration of value assigned to pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers, enums

The following class is given:

```
class Button {

public:

   enum Color{RED, GREEN, BLUE};
   Color color = RED;

   void setToBlue() {
      Color* colorPtr = &color;
      *colorPtr = BLUE;
      //colorPtr->BLUE;
   }

}
```

If I call `setToBlue()`, will `BLUE` not be destroyed until `Button` is destroyed? Why is the out commented instruction not valid?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is perfectly valid.

```
*colorPtr = BLUE;
```

copies the value of `BLUE` into the pointed to object. Which in this case is `color`, which is a member of `Button` and thus is guaranteed to exist until the `Button` object is destroyed.

Note that

```
   void setToBlue() {
      color = BLUE;
   }
```

Is exactly the same in this case.

To answer your edit:

> Why is the out commented instruction not valid?

Because what operator `->` does is the same as `(*colorPtr).`. The `.` operator is the member access operator, an enum doesn't have any members to access and thus it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a fundamental confusion here about what an enum is.  Probably the best way to see them for this sample is as a #define.

Imagine that instead you had

```
#define BLUE 2
```

and then did colour = BLUE; this would breakdown to colour = 2

Since '2' is now hard coded in the memory of the binary, it's scope is global.